# using Global Light in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, photoshop, dropshadow

I am developing UI for a Wpf application. I have designs build by designer in Adobe Photoshop CS3. I am going through them and achieving the same in my project using WPF. In PhotoShop, while setting Drop Shadow, there is option to select Angle and there is a CheckBox for
`Use Global Light`.

I got some [reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/10.0/help.html?content=WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7887.html) for this. but I don't know how to achieve this in WPF. In WPF, I am not able to find any such option with `DropShadowEffect`. Anybody help me plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is any similar concept for a drop shadow effect. That being said, you could use style so create your own GlobalLight style that would be used by your controls.

For example:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GlobalLight" TargetType="TextBlock">
     <Setter Property="Effect">
       <Setter.Value>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="2" Direction="-90" Color="Black" ShadowDepth="1"/>
       </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
      </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

  <TextBlock Text="Drop shadow effect text" Style="{StaticResource GlobalLight}" />
</Grid>
```

More examples of using the drop shadow effect can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748273.aspx).